# Use Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash with Fabric crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I use [CustomActivityOnCrash](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash) made by ereza and Google's Fabric.

I am going through one issue that is not classified by class, because I reported in `MyCrashActivity`.

For reference, the `Exception.printStackTrace()` in the crash area is received as an Intent.

```
public class MyCrashActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.abcdefg);

        StringBuffer crashErrorMsg = new StringBuffer();
        crashErrorMsg.append("\n").append(CustomActivityOnCrash.getAllErrorDetailsFromIntent(this, getIntent()));
        Crashlytics.logException(new Throwable(crashErrorMsg.toString())); // error report.
        sendReportAppCrash(crashErrorMsg.toString());
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I know. my fault. but, I don't know what to do about whether to divide `Crashlytics.logException()` and `MyCrashActivity`.

When these two are combined, All error reports are reported as a problem with "MyCrashActivity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I guess that fabric had reported error before crash.
so, It seems that there were two reports.
I removed fabric code to fix the problem.

`public class MyCrashActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.abcdefg);
        ...
    }
    ...
}`

As a result, I believe that this library is just for outputting a view gracefully prepared to die.

This question may seem somewhat stupid, but I hope it helps.